# InitialLdapContext returned LDAP: error code 49

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I ran into an issue when trying to connect to ldap server in my spring boot application.
I verified the URL, user name, and password are all valid using ADExplorer.
I also step trace the same information to make sure information is correct right before the call.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
if(ldapUsername != null) {
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
}
if(ldapPassword != null) {
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);
}
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);
env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSID");

ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);<==== exception thrown
return ctx;
```

```
ldap:
    host:
      ldapadserver: ldap://ldapserver.com
    search:
      ldapsearchbase: OU=AD Master OU,OU=###,DC=###,DC=###
    user:
      ldapusername: ####
      ldappassword: ENC(#####)
```

```
Exception while loading user configuration file : javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3261)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3207)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2993)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2907)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:347)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:225)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:243)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
```

Just an update:  I followed the advise and use the full DN string as ldapUserName and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data 52e` in the error message refers to the [Windows System Error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-#:%7E:text=of%20the%20domain.-,ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE,-1326%20(0x52E)), which is:

> **ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE**
>
> 1326 (0x52E)
>
> The user name or password is incorrect.

So it's definitely complaining about your credentials.

What format is the username in? You mention in the comment to the other answer, `cn=ldapuser`, but that won't work for AD. The format should be one of:

- Just the username (either `sAMAccountName` or `userPrincipalName`) e.g. `ldapuser`
- The domain\username, e.g. `DOMAIN\ldapuser`
- The distinguished name, e.g. `CN=ldapuser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com`

Comment: I tried env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn="+this.ldapUsername+", "+this.ldapSearchBase); however I still got the same error.  Using ADExplorer, I don't only need to supply short user name without domain name or search base though.

Comment: Does `"cn="+this.ldapUsername+", "+this.ldapSearchBase` evaluate to the actual `distinguishedName` of the user account? If not, then it is expected that it won't work.

Comment: When I try in ADExplorer, I can provide just the short username and it works.

Comment: I've read other examples like:    //"administrator@diamelle.local"
    envDC.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);  So how do I tell if I need to use a simple user name like in ADExplore, or username@domain , or  cn=username, <searchBaseStr>

Comment: You don't need to tell it which format to use. You just need to give it an accurate value. If you're going to use the distinguished name, you don't use the search base - you use the actual distinguished name of the account (the `distinguishedName` attribute on the account), which may or may not have anything to do with the search base.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel Luci. I use the full DN as ldapUserName and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say, but assume this is Microsoft Active Directory. Guessing you need this:
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

Also no idea what ENC(#####) is?

We have several examples known to work at:
https://github.com/jwilleke/Examples-JNDI/tree/master/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi

Comment: I'm using ldap:// instead of ldaps://, I guess env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl"); is not needed.  The ENC(###) is the encrypted password. I verified that the decrypted password is set in env before the initialLdapContext call.  I also tried put base after cn=ldapsuer but it did not help either.